# Inserting keys into a hash table of length 9

Tags: data-structures, hashtable, hash-function, modulo

So, I'm working on a problem that requires me to insert keys in order in a hash table. I stopped inserting after the 20 since there is not more room. I provide the following picture to help with context. I created the hash table, found the number of collisions and the load factor. Collisions are resolved by open addressing. Sorry this isn't a questions, I just need someone to look over it and tell me if its all correct.
[image: My finished work]

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want the final table verified based on your hash or are you asking for feedback on the function?

Comment: Need someone to verify my table.

Comment: FWIW, I mentally verified placements in your table, but didn't count the collisions while doing so.

Comment: I verified your table so please accept my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of errors and misunderstandings in your question.

- You state that you 'stopped inserting after 20' but you show 15 keys.
- There are 9 buckets in your hash table but then you state that the load factor is 1. Load factor is the number of keys (15 or 20) divided by the number of buckets (9) so it is not 1.
- In a hash function `h(k,i)` `k` is the key and `i` is the number of buckets. In your case `i` is 9 and so the function `(k mod 9 + 5i) mod 9` really makes no sense.
- All hash functions should end with `mod i`.
- There are not 15 collisions in the keys you provided. A collision only occurs when there's a previous value in the table.

This is all explained in the wikipedia article on [hashtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

With the clarifications in the comments below this answer in mind, I used the following code to verify your conclusions:

```
public class Hashing {
    private static final int SIZE = 9;
    private final int[] keys = new int[SIZE];
    private int collisions = 0;

    public void add(int key) {
        int attempt = 0;
        while (keys[hash(key, attempt)] > 0)
            attempt++;
        collisions += attempt;
        keys[hash(key, attempt)] = key;
    }

    private int hash(int key, int attempt) {
        return (key % SIZE + 5 * attempt) % SIZE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hashing table = new Hashing();
        Stream.of(28, 5, 15, 19, 10, 17, 33, 12, 20).forEach(table::add);
        System.out.println("Table " + Arrays.toString(table.keys));
        System.out.println("Collisions " + table.collisions);
    }   
}
```

And received the following output:

```
Table [20, 28, 19, 33, 12, 5, 15, 10, 17]
Collisions 15
```

Comment: The question is poorly stated, resulting in some misunderstandings.  I'd hazard the following clarifications: *i* in the hash function will be meant to count the rehashing attempts caused by collisions, i.e. h(k,0) yields the first bucket to try, h(k,1) the first alternative bucket etc..  The table as shown is full with not all requested keys inserted successfully, hence the *"stopped after (key) 20"* and *"load factor 1"*.  Finally, the 15(?) collisions mentioned presumably occurred while populating the table: e.g. h(19,0) == 1 which was already occupied by 28, h(19,1) == 6 collides with 5...

Comment: @TonyD ok that makes more sense now. Thanks.